# Zip a directory and delete it right afterwards using shutil

Tags: python, zip, archive, shutil

I am trying to zip a given directory and delete the directory right afterwards.
Therefore I am using the `shutil` module.

The method that I implemented to do so looks like this:

```
def _zip(fulldname, delete_after=False):
"""
Zip a directory

:param dname: The full name of the directory
:type dname: str
:param delete_after: Delete the directory after it has been zipped?
:type delete_after: bool
:return: the full name of the zip file
:rtype: str
"""
if not os.path.isdir(fulldname):
    raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT),
                            fulldname)
fullzipfname = shutil.make_archive(fulldname, "zip", root_dir=fulldname,
                            base_dir="./")
if delete_after:
    shutil.rmtree(fulldname)
return fullzipfname
```

When I execute it I am either getting the following error or the method simply runs forever (i.e. gets stuck at the `shutil.rmtree()` method):

```
File "/media/sf_projects/robot_framework/rfw_rest_api/src/main/rfw_rest_api/rfw_rest_api.py", line 126, in exec_robot
output_arc = core._zip(proc_output_dir, delete_after=True)
File "/media/sf_projects/robot_framework/rfw_rest_api/src/main/core.py", line 147, in _zip
shutil.rmtree(fulldname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 498, in rmtree
onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 496, in rmtree
os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: '../../output/pcap_based_fuzzer_210127_120207'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution that completely avoids `shutil`:

```
def _zip(fulldname, delete_after=False):
"""
Zip a directory

:param fulldname: The full name of the directory
:type fulldname: str
:param delete_after: Delete the directory after it has been zipped?
:type delete_after: bool
:return: the name of the zip file
:rtype: str
"""
if not os.path.isdir(fulldname):
    raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT),
                            fulldname)
fullzipfname = fulldname + ".zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(fullzipfname, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fulldname):
        for _dir in dirs:
            zipf.write(os.path.join(root, _dir),
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, _dir),
                                       os.path.join(fulldname)))
        for file in files:
            zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file),
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file),
                                       os.path.join(fulldname)))
logger.debug(f"Created zip directory {fullzipfname}")
if delete_after:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fulldname, topdown=False):
        for file in files:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
        for _dir in dirs:
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, _dir))
    os.rmdir(fulldname)
    logger.debug(f"Removed original directory {fulldname}")
return fullzipfname.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
```

I also noticed that `shutil`'s `make_archive` sometimes runs like forever.
Although using `os.walk()` and `zipfile.ZipFile` isn't noticeably faster in the most cases it still seems more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this program (or another process) is accessing a file in `fulldname` directory while you are trying to delete it. Judging by the error "Text file busy", it is probable that the said file is a binary being executed. I would make sure that no files from that directory remain open in the program when the function is called.

Also, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive), `base_dir` parameter of `make_archive` must be relative to `root_dir` parameter. Are you sure that the variable `fulldname` and the path it holds satisfiy this property?

Comment: 1) How would I ensure that no binary file is executed when I try to delete the directory? The call fails when it tries to delete the empty directory but when I look into it after the directory is in fact empty. 2) Maybe I understood base_dir wrong but I thought like this I would specify that the relative path of all zipped files in the zipped directory is ./

Comment: gotta correct myself... I meant relative path prefix not path. With `./` I wanted to ensure that if I zip the directory `exampledir/` which contains a file `examplefile` the zip file contains this file under the path `exampledir/examplefile`.